# Keycloak client baseurl is not accepting url without http

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-connect

I am developing react app. And keeping keycloak for signup. After completing signup keycloak is triggering an email for email verification. When the user verify I want to redirect that verified user to this url e.g. com.abcd.xyzApp/*(My app). But I am not able to set this URL(com.abcd.xyzApp/*) in keycloak baseurl without http. Getting error "Error! Base URL is not a valid URL"

Is there any solution? Thanks

Comment: OIDC is working on top of http(s) protocol, why you want to redirect user to non http destination? At least you could setup http(s) endpoint that will redirect user to your specific url, and use this endpoint in Keycloak settings.

Answer (score 0):

This should work by using the `redirect_uri` query parameter when initiating the login. However, this `redirect_uri` param is lost in case email verification gets triggered.
I already filed a ticket for this a while ago (see [KEYCLOAK-16860](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-16860)).

You may want to redirect to a custom http(s) endpoint and initiate an app specific redirect from there as mentioned [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/custom-scheme-for-native-mobile-apps/1773/6).